# c++ memory leak detector 'asan' cannot detect memory leaks and cannot redirect asan output log to a file

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I make a test code as this

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void fn(){
    int *a= new int[10];
    a[11] = 3;                                                                                                      
}

int main(){
    while(1){
       fn();
    } 

return 0;
}
```

and I compile it and run

```
(base) root@acnszavl00036:~/project/test# g++ -fsanitize=address -fno-omit-frame-pointer -g main.cpp 
(base) root@acnszavl00036:~/project/test# ./a.out 
=================================================================
==3857==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x60400000dffc at pc 0x000000400a2b bp 0x7fffe8da6b70 sp 0x7fffe8da6b60
WRITE of size 4 at 0x60400000dffc thread T0
    #0 0x400a2a in fn() /root/project/test/main.cpp:9
    #1 0x400a3c in main /root/project/test/main.cpp:16
    #2 0x7fb2a947b82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
    #3 0x400908 in _start (/root/project/test/a.out+0x400908)

0x60400000dffc is located 4 bytes to the right of 40-byte region [0x60400000dfd0,0x60400000dff8)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #0 0x7fb2a9c406b2 in operator new[](unsigned long) (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.2+0x996b2)
    #1 0x4009e7 in fn() /root/project/test/main.cpp:8
    #2 0x400a3c in main /root/project/test/main.cpp:16
    #3 0x7fb2a947b82f in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow /root/project/test/main.cpp:9 fn()
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c087fff9ba0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff9bb0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff9bc0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff9bd0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff9be0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
=>0x0c087fff9bf0: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa 00 00 00 00 00[fa]
  0x0c087fff9c00: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff9c10: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff9c20: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff9c30: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c087fff9c40: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Heap right redzone:      fb
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack partial redzone:   f4
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
==3857==ABORTING
```

## Question1:

obviously, memory overflow can be detected, however, when I change the code as below, and compile it and run, there are not asan output to info memory leak which should have, where is wrong?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

void fn(){
    int *a= new int[10];
    //a[11] = 3;    comment this                                                                                                  
}

int main(){
    while(1){
       fn();
    } 

return 0;
}
```

## Question2:

and also， I use the first code (which can make asan output log), but set a environment variable in order to redirect asan log to a file as below, and run the program, but there is nothing in file /root/asan.log

```
export ASAN_OPTIONS=detect_leaks=1:malloc_context_size=15:log_path=/root/asan.log:
```

Comment: Your output is going to `/root/asan.log`. Are you running as superuser? If so, I'd try running as an ordinary user. Or, if not running as root, you should probably try a different log file (e.g. `/home/myuser/asan.log`)

Comment: yes, I run it as root